# Weird GLSL fragment shader behaviour - running time

Tags: c++, glsl, fragment-shader

I have one fragment shader, which gives me a headache, because it sometimes runs fast, and sometimes very slow, on the same data.

This shader is run by two different classes, using the same calling code. (there used to be different calling codes, but now it is copy-paste to be sure it is not a source of this behaviour). Only one of these classes work at any single run of app, I select them before clicking "start". Clicking "stop" and then "start" again can lead to different running times.

When called from first class, it gives me a consistent running times of 6~7 ms per frame.
When called from second class, running times are either the same as from first class (~30% of runs), or about 3~4 times slower (18~24ms per frame). There is no pattern when it will be fast and when it will be slow. I could start my app, and first run could be slow and second run could be fast, or vice versa, or any other combination.

These classes are both parts of their respective workflows. Both workflows gave consistent times before current changes. Nothing other than these two classes was changed. When first of these two classes was updated, it was also OK - both of them. Weird behaviour started when I made similar changes in second class. Currently shader and its calling code is now the same in both classes.

I have also noticed that:

- when this shader works slower, then all other shaders are also slower (but not 3~4x, only some 50% slower).
- having running Skype in background, calling a coworker and sharing my desktop has very positive effect on running times - shader works fast more often, ~80% of runs. Especially when my app is started when desktop sharing is already running.
- disabling some drawing also has some effect, by SLOWING shader even more often (only ~10% of runs are fast), and it is even slower (24~30ms).

I have no idea why it happens. I can't show the code, and I'm not expecting exact solution, but can someone point me in some direction, where to look for errors or something?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! As you stated your question, it is difficult to tell what could be going wrong (see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)). Can you post the code involved? Also, too many elements are interacting; can you narrow it down to a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I really cannot post the code... I know that it is really fuzzy question, but I wasn't expecting exact solutions but rather some pointers like "check XYZ for potential [conflicts/errors/bottlenecks etc.]". My question can be simplified to "Why some shader sometimes works longer and sometimes shorter on the same data and how it can be connected to other GPU activities like Skype and/or in-app drawing".

Comment: As it is, you question is equivalent to asking vague debugging guidelines for shader performance; that’s too broad and it’s likely to get flagged and/or stay unanswered.

Comment: How are you measuring the timing? The first thing to check in any GPU performance situation is that one is not including other execution in the timing scope. This is difficult as so many API calls are asynchronous.

Comment: I measure time after a glFinish(), to be sure that shader has finished.

Comment: Please use an OpenGL profiler [like vOGL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VOGL), for example, and show us its output on a «good» and a «bad» pass. The source of the problem shall become way clearer — not only for us, but for you too.